# Mysqli auto incremented value does not work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying by using mysqli prepared statements insert values into my database. The problem is that I get an error saying `Prepare failed: (1136) Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`. If I add one question mark I fix that error but again, I get another one which says `Binding parameters failed: (0) #3 Execute failed: (2031) No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement`.

My database structure looks like this: http://cl.ly/image/2x3i162V290L, and my PHP looks like this:

```
   <?php 

include 'db_connect.php';
include 'functions.php';

sec_session_start();

$name = $_POST['name'];
$artist = $_POST['artist'];
$url = $_POST['url'];
$lyrics = $_POST['lyrics'];
$lyrtime = "";


if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO song VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"))) {
     echo "#1 Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

/* Prepared statement, stage 2: bind and execute */
if (!$stmt->bind_param("isssss", $_SESSION['user_id'], $name, $artist, $url, $lyrics, $lyrtime)) {
    echo "#2 Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "#3 Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

/* explicit close recommended */
$stmt->close();

?>
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: primary key is autoincremented u may need to pass NULL as the first value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the fields you're setting

```
"INSERT INTO song VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"
```

should be

```
"INSERT INTO song (userid, name, artist, lyric, url, lyrtime)VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"
```

else the first ? is assumed to be the id, and is used instead of
the auto-incremented value if you don't declare the fields first.
(only 6 '?' instead of 7)

You also need to remove one bind parameter since you aren't passing the id PK

```
    /* Prepared statement, stage 2: bind and execute */
    if (!$stmt->bind_param("issss", $_SESSION['user_id'], 
           $name, $artist, $url, $lyrics,$lyrtime)) {
    echo "#2 Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^---- 7 placeholders

bind_param("isssss",
            ^^^^^^--- 6 placeholders
```

Which is **EXACTLY** what the error message was telling you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forget about primary key. You can use query like

```
Insert INTO TABLE(COL1, COL2) VALUES(1,2)
```

without primary key. In this case your table TABLE(PRIM_COL, COL1, COL2).
Or you need to place null in place where must be primary key.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO song VALUES (null,?,?,?,?,?,?)")
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be help.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
Hope this works